# Are obvious parentheses bad?

Tags: java, operator-precedence, parentheses

In the example:

```
float w = (View.WIDTH / 4) * 3;
```

The parentheses do not alter the outcome (right?) so are therefore redundant.
Yet I find they make the intention of the code clearer. It is a style faux pas to have such redundant parentheses?

Comment: This is a bit of a subjective question, but I would always put the parenthesis there just to be clear what you intend to happen.

Comment: I think doing so to increase the code readability is always a good practice.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for getting opinions rather than facts as answers.

Comment: I don't believe anything that makes code easier to read can be considered bad, even in obvious cases like this.

Comment: No if it increases the readability, even if its obvious.

Comment: As Kevin DiTraglia just pointed out, it's a matter of readability. Even if the parentheses are redundant to the compiler, they are definitely important to transmit what you want to do to the human readers (for instance, the future maintainers of your code).

Comment: It makes maintenance easier. Imagine if expression gets complicated, it should be hard for the next one in line to create a mess.

Comment: If WIDTH is an `int` you may be better off doing `*3/4` this is clearer to me in any case as it say three quarters.  Note: this is not the same as three time one quarter as you have it. e.g. 7 / 4 * 3 = 3, 7 * 3 / 4 = 5;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parentheses do not affect the outcome of an expression you should ask yourself:
'Will adding these parentheses make this expression easier or harder to read?'
If the answer is the former, feel free to add them.

So no - it's not bad in this example, but it can be bad if used excessively.

Answer (score 1):

Adding parenthesis when it's already obvious how the code will be executed is generally bad. Whether or not something is obvious is a matter of opinion.

Otherwise they're generally good.

For your example it makes sense to add them (to me), although this would eliminate the need for them:

```
float w = 3 * View.WIDTH / 4
```

or:

```
float w = View.WIDTH * 3 / 4
```